# spring custom validator constructor

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have custom validator

```
public class SimpleValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Simple, String> {

    private SimpleDao dao;   

    //@Autowired
    public SimpleValidator (SimpleDao<String> dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Simple annotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return dao.someAction(value);
    }
}

public class MyService {
    //@Autowired
    private Validator validator;
    public MyService (Validator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;  
    }

    public BindingResult SomeMethod(SimpleDto dto) {
        BindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(dto, "dto");
        validator.validate(dto, result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I use annotation @Autowired (for validator in MyService class) and try to validate some dto, it's validated successfully. But when I try to use xml config

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.BeanValidationPostProcessor">
  <property name="validator" ref="validator"/>
</bean>

<bean id="simpleValidator" class="org.jtalks.jcommune.model.validation.validators.SimpleValidator">
    <constructor-arg ref="validatorDAO"/>  
</bean>

<bean id="myService" class="org.jtalks.jcommune.service.transactional.MyService">
    <constructor-arg ref="validator"/>
</bean>

<bean id="validatorDAO"
    class="org.jtalks.jcommune.model.dao.hibernate.ValidatorHibernateDao">
  <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="mappingResources">
 ...
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">
      org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    </prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charset">${encoding}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
  </props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

I get exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.jtalks.jcommune.model.validation.validators.SimpleValidator]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jtalks.jcommune.model.validation.validators.SimpleValidator.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
... 126 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jtalks.jcommune.model.validation.validators.SimpleValidator.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2730)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2004)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
... 127 more
```

Is there able to use xml configuration for validators? How can I instantiate validator with SimpleDao without using @Autowired annotation?

Comment: `No default constructor found` - message is clear.

Comment: Yes, I can create default constructor. But I need to instatiate Validator with SimpleDao. If I create default constructor and setter for dao, exception not occured, but the dao will be null. I think spring doesn't use xml config for resolve dependencies for validators, but why?

Comment: spring will resolve all the dependencies from the XML file. can update your question with validatorDao dependencies.

Comment: with first load application I see that it is really so (validator initialized successfully with xml config), but when I use validator.validate(...) I get the problems

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following

```
<bean id="simpleValidator" class="com.example.validators.SimpleValidator">
    <property name="dao" ref="validatorDao"/>
</bean>
```

**Use this one.**

```
<bean id="simpleValidator" class="com.example.validators.SimpleValidator">
      <constructor-arg ref="validatorDao"/>     
</bean>
```

**Update**

Considering SimpleDao interface implemented in ValidatorHibernateDao.

```
 <bean id="simpleDao"  class"org.jtalks.jcommune.model.dao.hibernate.SimpleDao" abstract="true"/>

<bean id="validatorDAO"
   class="org.jtalks.jcommune.model.dao.hibernate.ValidatorHibernateDao" parent="simpleDao">
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

  public class SimpleValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Simple, String> {

     private SimpleDao<String> dao;   

  }
```

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. There is  <constructor-arg ref="validatorDao"/>   of course. I tried two cases: 1. constructor (with SimpleDao) 2. Default constructor with SimpleDao setter

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same result